# jQuery Mobile – content grid with relative height

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to build a grid in jquery mobile that, for the purpose of an example, resembles something like a number pad.

What I'm going for is that the grid takes up a given percentage (e.g. 75%) of the page's height. My attempt was to stretch the `content` section to `height: 100%`, the actual grid to `height: 75%` and then each block to `height: 20%` (because it's 5 rows).

However, it [doesn't seem to work (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6XZP/1/). Inspecting the elements, it appears that the `content` section ignores the `height: 100%` (the `page` wrapper does have the full size). But I can't seem to find the reason.

Can someone point me to why this is happening and how I can stretch the grid to take up 75% of the available height?

It appears that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951534/jquery-mobile-button-height-in-percent) question is about the same problem, but there is no answer to be found there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Q2ABZ/

**CSS:**

```
div[data-role="content"] {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}

div.ui-grid-b {
    height: 75%;
}

.ui-block-a, .ui-block-b, .ui-block-c {
    height: 20%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was fast. Is there an explanation why this is necessary? Also – I didn't mention this – I need this grid to be positioned on the bottom of the page, but removing `top: 0` breaks it again.

Comment: Addition: I can, of course, fill the upper space with a `div` of the correct percentage. But an explanation of why it works this way would still be nice.

Comment: This is because jQuery Mobile content div has variable height that changes according to its content. So we must force it to cover available space. There are two solutions for this problem and you can find them here: http://www.gajotres.net/using-google-maps-javascript-api-v3-with-jquery-mobile/ . Article talks about google maps integration into jQuery Mobile page which covers this problem.

Comment: Thank you. Removing `top: 0` from the `content` section was non-sense anyway. I'll check out that link now.

Comment: I think I got it working the way I want to now, awesome. Thanks again! I'll accept as soon as SO lets me.